# Github Action for deploying Angular App to Firebase - No files were found with the provided path: project_name/dist/. No artifacts will be uploaded

Tags: angular, firebase, github, github-actions, artifacts

We are trying to auto-deploy our angular app using GitHub actions on firebase hosting but we are facing an error on the build step for our app showing that An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/runner/work/...../dist'

on GitHub actions, Getting below error:

```
Run npm run build

> ngx-admin@0.1.0 build
> ng build

Warning: Support was requested for IE 11 in the project's browserslist configuration. IE 11 support is deprecated since Angular v12.
For more information, see https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
- Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/runner/work/project_name/project_name/dist'
See "/tmp/ng-gy4uE4/angular-errors.log" for further details.
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
```

Please find our GitHub actions .yml file code below:

```
name: Auto Release

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - test_release_branch

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build and Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Initialize Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@master
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: dist
          path: dist/
      - name: Build
        run: npm run build
      - name: Deploy
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting:site-name
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```

I can install, build, and deploy manually from my console just fine. I thought this error might have something to do with my dist directory's location on git, Any thoughts on what this might be?